# UICollectionview Append data to Array Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a group chatting app which i am able to add users to the group whenever I click on the user. The group member selection page looks like this:

[image]

whenever I click on a user, it will be added to the collectionView on top. My collectionView is placed on top while tableview at the bottom.
Once i click on a user, it looks like:

[image]

I am having a bug whereby it doesnt matter where I click, even if I click on the second row,user tester 2 or third row,user apple, the collectionView shows me the first user, and then it shows the second user appended to it and third and fourth. How should I make it show the user of whichever I clicked?

for my collectionView:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return chosenUser.count
}

func updateCollectionView() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}

var chosenUser: [User] = []

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ChosenUserCollectionViewCell

    let user = users[indexPath.row]

    cell.chosenUserImage.layer.cornerRadius = 30
    cell.chosenUserImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
    cell.chosenUserImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

    if let profileImageUrl = user.profileImageUrl {
        cell.chosenUserImage.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(profileImageUrl)
    } else {
        cell.chosenUserImage.image = UIImage(named: "profileIcon")
    }

    return cell
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return chosenUser.count
}
```

as of my tableview:

```
protocol toRefresh {
func updateCollectionView()}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let user = users[indexPath.row]
    self.chosenUser.append(user)
    updateCollectionView()
    }
}
```

May i know is there any mistakes i done on my tableview DidSelectRowAt?

Comment: Why do some users have no picture? What is the collection view expected to show if there is no picture? May we see the `itemForRowAt` and `cellForRowAt` implementations?

Comment: I have updated the code for my collectionView. There are no pictures as I have not given the user some picture. I have actually asked this question twice,A downvote is appreciated if they can tell me what details I have missed out. I am asking sincerely and not here to play

Comment: I think in Your collectionView **cellForRow** should make use of **ChoosenUser** Array not your main array **users** which you have used to populate tableView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in Your collectionView **cellForRow** should make use of **ChoosenUser** Array not your main array **users** which you have used to populate tableView

Your work Flow

in TableView DidSelect You are appending `Selected User` in self.chosenUser Array as which is correct

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let user = users[indexPath.row]
    /// appending user
    self.chosenUser.append(user)
    updateCollectionView()
    }
}
```

Now coming to collectionView - Right you returned your chosen User Array count

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return chosenUser.count
}
```

Now when it comes to Dequeue User in collectionView CellForRow

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ChosenUserCollectionViewCell

    /// Here You did The mistake - 
    /// You did used main Array **Users**
    let user = users[indexPath.row]

    /// You actually need
    let user = choosenUser[indexPath.row] 

    /// What's Happening?
    /// You selected one user from tableView Appended it to newArray
    /// You Setted collectionView count according to new Array
    /// But you used main Array
    /// ---------------------Example-----------------
    ///Case -> Count is 1 - First user from mainArray will be shown
    /// Case -> count is 2 - First two user from mainArray Users will be shown
    cell.chosenUserImage.layer.cornerRadius = 30
    cell.chosenUserImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
    cell.chosenUserImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

    if let profileImageUrl = user.profileImageUrl {
        cell.chosenUserImage.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(profileImageUrl)
    } else {
        cell.chosenUserImage.image = UIImage(named: "profileIcon")
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Happy to Help, Welcome